# No jquery events working properly inside form tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $("document").ready(function () {

            $("#done").click(function () {
                $("#nm").hide();

            });
        });
    </script>
```

But when I use form tag it doesn't work. When I run the code, the validation stayed for few seconds and then gone.. But in the case when I remove the `<form>`, it runs well. Why does this happen?

```
    <form id="frm1" method="post"  >
        Name:    <input type="text" id="nm"/><br>
        E-Mail:  <input type="email" id="eml"/><br>
        Password:<input type="password" id="pass"/><br>

        <input type="submit" id="done"  value="SUBMIT"/>


    </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to pass an event and use `preventDefault()` to prevent the form from submitting on click:

```
$("#done").click(function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $("#nm").hide();
 });
```

Comment: Better to prevent the form's `submit` event than a click event

Answer (score 1):

You could use the event as in the example above or avoid using it and return false instead:

```
        $("#done").click(function () {
            $("#nm").hide();
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: The syntax seems easier to me. But there is an additional explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false

Comment: It means there are two options you can treat before an action of an element from happening.
This is suits good as well as the first answer.